# Unable to understand interfaces in typescript?

Tags: typescript, oop, interface, typescript2.0

I am new to typescript. I have come across a tutorial on offical website of typescript.

```
interface ClockConstructor {
    new (hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface;
}
interface ClockInterface {
    tick(): void;
}

function createClock(ctor: ClockConstructor, hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface {
    return new ctor(hour, minute);
}

class DigitalClock implements ClockInterface {
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
    tick() {
        console.log("beep beep");
    }
}
class AnalogClock implements ClockInterface {
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
    tick() {
        console.log("tick tock");
    }
}

let digital = createClock(DigitalClock, 12, 17);
let analog = createClock(AnalogClock, 7, 32);
```

I can not understand how

```
interface ClockConstructor {
    new (hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface;
}
```

is working.

Also, `createClock(DigitalClock, 12, 17);` in this function name of class is just passed not any object.

Please help me in understanding.

Comment: "name of class" is actually a constructor function. createClock calls it and returns object created.

Comment: And `ClockConstructor` is the type of constructor function which creates `ClockInterface` instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces are descriptions of other object.

```
interface ClockConstructor {
    new (hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface;
}
```

`ClockConstructor` describes a callable object that can be invoked with the `new` operator. What kind of object can be invoked with the `new` operator? A class. Note I am not referring to a class instance but to the class itself. Such an interface is useful when we want to type a variable that can contain a class that can be built by invoking it with specific parameters.

`createClock(DigitalClock, 12, 17);` passes a specific class `DigitalClock` to a parameetr that must be a class with a constructor that takes the specified arguments.

Comment: So at run time it replaces new (hour:number,minute:number) with new DigitalClock(hour:number,minute:number)

Comment: @DhirajKumar At compile time ts checks that `DigitalClock` has the constructor with parameters `(hour:number,minute:number)` when you try to pass it t the function `createClock`. At runtime `ctor` will contain either the class `DigitalClock` (in the first call) or `AnalogClock` (in the second call) so invoking `new ctor ...` will have the same effect as calling `new DigitalClock ...` and `new AnalogClock ...`  respectively.